# Database connection failure - Netbeans 8.1 - MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, phpmyadmin

Hello fellow programmers,

Still pretty new at programming - connecting to Databases and stuff.

I will post 6 pictures with the code I have, and the problem I have. I have no idea wat im doing wrong...

I can connect in Netbeans with the database but apparently if I run the app, there is an error.

I hope someone can help me out here...

I configured the MySQL database with port 2121
(password is root and username is root)
[image: As you can see - port 2121]

In phpMyadmin everything works fine, so the database is live.
(Focus on VivesBike)
[image: phpMyadmin]

Connection is correctly made in Netbeans under "services"
[image: connection works]

My connection manager I have
[image: connectionmanager]

And last but not least....
As you can see everything is filled in correctly...
[image: db.properties]

But still I manage to have this :

[image: error]

If I need to write the codes in here.. no problem. 
Or I can send the project to someone to help me out but I cant seem to find the problem.

(sorry if this seems like a dumb question)

EDIT :

This is the code for the DBproperties class :

```
package database;

import exception.DatabaseException;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Properties;


public class DbProperties {
private static String url;
private static String user;
private static String password;
private static String driver;

private DbProperties() throws DatabaseException{
    Properties dbProperties = new Properties();
    try(InputStream in = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("properties/DB.properties")){
        //File tmp = File.createTempFile(String.valueOf(in.hashCode()), "temp");
        //tmp.deleteOnExit();
        //try(FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(tmp)){
        dbProperties.load(in);
        url = dbProperties.getProperty("url");
        user = dbProperties.getProperty("user");
        password = dbProperties.getProperty("password");
        driver = dbProperties.getProperty("driver");

        }catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            throw new DatabaseException("File (DB.properties) not found: "+ex);
        }
   // }catch (IOException ex){
     //   throw new DatabaseException("File (DB.properties) not found: "+ex);
    //}
}

public static String getUrl() throws DatabaseException{
    if(url == null){
        DbProperties dbProp = new DbProperties();
    }
    return url;
}

public static String getUser() throws DatabaseException{
    if(user == null){
        DbProperties dbProp = new DbProperties();
    }
    return user;
}

public static String getPassword() throws DatabaseException{
    if(password == null){
        DbProperties dbProp = new DbProperties();
    }
    return password;
}

public static String getDriver() throws DatabaseException{
    if(driver == null){
        DbProperties dbProp = new DbProperties();
    }
    return driver;
}
```

}

EDIT 2 :

If there is a problem with the driver I would see it here...
[image]

This is the result of the build
[image]

(I hope this is wat you ment)

EDIT 3:

[image]

[image]

Kind regards,
Dylan

Comment: Are you sure the MySQL JDBC driver is visible to your Java program?  Can you show us the relevant code for your `DbProperties` class?

Comment: hi, I updated my question with the code of that class.

Comment: Have you verified that _any_ of your properties are actually being loaded?  Can you check this?

Comment: check EDIT 2... I hope this is what you meant

Comment: Yes but where does the `driver` actually get initialized?

Comment: in my connection manager class?

Comment: I hate defacing your question like this, but can you verify that every one of your string properties are actually defined in `ConnectionManager.getConnection()` ?

Comment: And could you post the full stack trace from the exception?  This might tell us what actually went wrong.

Comment: Done, (I am from Belgium so my English is not that good... I hope you meant this with "full stack trace"

Comment: `JDWP Transport dt_socket failed to intialize` ... this appears to be your real error, q.v. [here](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=89639).  I have never seen this, but I suspect this is what is causing the database layer to not be working.

Comment: thanks for your help so far... but I have no idea how to fix this. kind regards

Comment: @Dylanbeginner21, Did you add `mysql-connector.jar` file to your project this might be the error.

Comment: @Shashanth, thanks!!! thats exactely what the problem was (silly me). Problem is solved now! :D